# PHP SESSIONS, COOKIES and Remember Me function

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have the following code, when a user logs in, they are presented with two text boxes and a checkbox.

Setting the three cookies, `username`, `password` and `remember` all work and the log in script itself is comepletely fine (I appreciate that storing hashed passwords in the cookie isn't best practice but for now it will do).

What happens though, is id the user re-visits the `login.php` page (this one) while they are already logged in the cookies are removed one-by-one as the $_POST condition is not being met and therefore the lines below are being executed. How can I prevent this from happening. Also, any suggestions to clean up the code as I will no doubt end up with a lot of repeated code will be appreciated. Thanks

`snippet from the 'login.php' page below`

```
} elseif (!$_POST['remember']) {
    $past = time() - 100;
    if (isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
        setcookie('remember', '', $past);
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
        setcookie('username', '', $past);
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
        setcookie('password', '', $past);
    }
}
```

`login.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
include("includes/config.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

$username = "";
$password = "";

if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {

    $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $password = $_COOKIE['password'];

} elseif (isset($_POST['username'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = md5(DB_SALT.$password);

}

$sql = "SELECT * from tblMembers WHERE username = :username";
$query = $odb->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":username" => $username));
$results = $query->fetchAll();
if($results !== FALSE && $query->rowCount()>0) {
    if($results[0]['passwordHash'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $results[0]['userID'];

        if($_POST['remember']) {
            $month = time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
            setcookie('remember', $_POST['username'], $month);
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], $month);
            setcookie('password', $results[0]['passwordHash'], $month);
        } elseif (!$_POST['remember']) {
            $past = time() - 100;
            if (isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
                setcookie('remember', '', $past);
            } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
                setcookie('username', '', $past);
            } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
                setcookie('password', '', $past);
            }
        }


        header("Location: "."index.php");
    } else {
        echo "password incorrect";
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
Username:&nbsp;
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
    echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"username\" name=\"username\" maxlength=\"40\" value=".$_COOKIE['username'].">";
} else {
    echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"username\" name=\"username\" maxlength=\"40\" value=\"\">";
}
?>
Password:&nbsp;<input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="50">
Remember Me:&nbsp;
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"remember\" name=\"remember\" checked=\"checked\">";
} else {
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"remember\" name=\"remember\">";
}
?>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How this cookie question is related to mysql and PDO?

Comment: Because it contains MySQL and PDO code, all the other classes that I have are related to this so I guessed that if I reach out to more people then I will get a more tailored answer relating to what I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says exactly that this should happen. After the first request the `remember` POST parameter will not be set anymore and thus the if-statement evaluates to `true`. It then will delete the first cookie. Next time it will delete the second, because the first already doesn't exist anymore.

Maybe you should replace this line:

```
elseif (!$_POST['remember']) {
```

with this:

```
elseif (!$_POST['remember'] && !$_COOKIE['remember']) {
```

And you should get rid of the `elseif`s in there, because you probably want to delete all cookies. Just put `if` and it should do as you wish.

And on a side note: `!$var` is not the proper way to check if a value is set. Use `!isset($var)` instead.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `elseif (!isset($_POST['remember']) && (!isset($_COOKIE['remember'])))`

Comment: Yes...if you base your decision on the existence of the variables. If the value matters as well, you can safely add `!$_POST['remember']` with another `&&` to the condition as well. Just make sure that the `isset()` is always checked before you actually use the variable.